# How to handle AG-Grid API actions inside redux or component functions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, redux-toolkit

For a project I'm working on we use the AG-Grid with the data loaded from a server. 
Users will have the option to upload files and those files will be displayed on the grid immediately after starting the upload (with an uploading status).

**The goal** is to refresh the grid after an upload is done, so when our React Redux asyncThunk function succeeds. This because that way we update the grid when an uploading status has changed, so that the user does not have to refresh the browser to see the latest updates of his upload.

**What is the problem?**

We currently use an AG-Grid api reference in our other components to trigger similar AG-Grid actions (such as a reload). 
But, we cannot pass that reference through to our React Redux slice, as you cannot have a non-serializable value in there.

**Possible solutions?**

Is there a way you can pass a reference of the AG-Grid api throug to a React Redux slice to trigger actions in an asyncThunk (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)?

Is there a way to use that reference in a file where we export a function that would trigger an action of that AG-Grid api reference? So this could be called in the asyncThunk.

If there is another way this might be possible, please let me know.
 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm very familiar with redux and redux-toolkit but I'm not familiar with AG-Grid.  If you could post some sample code (like the components which use the reload) that would be helpful. You can use `createAsyncThunk` to create a function that must be called with some AG-Grid component as an argument.  You don't want to have non-serializable values in the state or in the actions which are ultimately dispatched by your asyncThunk.  But it is fine to have them in the *action creator* which is created by `createAsyncThunk`.

Comment: I just learned that the arguments you use when you call the asyncThunk action creator end up getting attached to the action as `action.meta.arg` https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions.  That means that what I said before is incorrect because the arguments of the action creator need to be serializable. A hacky roundabout would be a double arrow function such that the actual action creator is not called with the unserializable component, but that component would be in the scope of the payload creator due to the outer function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the upload is complete, you can dispatch an action through thunk that adds this information to the redux state (like in the form of `state.uploadStatus = 'uploaded'`). Access this `uploadStatus` in the component where you have AG-Grid api reference using `useSelector`. Then, you can track changes in the `uploadStatus` in a `useEffect` hook, and trigger grid refresh acccordingly.

```
const uploadStatus = useSelector(uploadStatusSelector)

useEffect (()=> {
   refreshGrid()
}, [uploadStatus]);
```

If you are uploading multiple files and need to refresh the grid every time any of those files is uploaded, then set `uploadStatus` to be an array and push something like `fileId` into the array when any of those files is uploaded successfully.